# How to Set Text To a disabled JTextArea

Tags: java, string, swing, jtextarea

I want some help on how to paste a copied `String` to a disabled `JTextArea`.

I'm trying to do:

```
Input.copy();
ExprTextArea.paste();
```

Where input is the `String` to be copied and `ExprTextArea` is the element which the copied `String` must be pasted.

Comment: please tag carefully. `Swing` tag should be tagged because of question belongs to Java Swings

Comment: `setText();` doesn't work?

Comment: @FastSnail No, i've tryied also with `setTest()` but doesn't work.

Comment: `ExprTextArea.append("Text") `  try this ? Is It Working or not?

Comment: Yes, it's working! Thank you, @VikrantKashyap

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
ExprTextArea.append("Text"); //append will work in this Case.
```

because `setText()` Method will not work because of Disabled.

Comment: wrong .`setText()` and append are different .`settext` replace the text while `append` append the text .disable mean we cannot type or paste text to it .but programmatically we can set text .